# Vue.js dynamic class variable in variable

Tags: css, vue.js, variables

I want to ask you, if its possible doing this with dynamic class like this.
`<div :class="'outofstock.item_' + item.id ? 'bg-green-500' : 'bg-red-500' ">`
If exist solution, I cant find a rigth syntax for this. Thank you for a answers.

thats a example what I try to do. I need a result outofstock.item_1, outofstock.item_2 and outofstock.item_3 in :claas

```
<template>
<ul>
    <li v-for="item in items">
        <div :class="'outofstock.item_' + item.id ? 'bg-green-500' : 'bg-red-500' ">
            {{ item.name }}
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</template>

<script>   
    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                items: [{id: 1, name: 'monitor'}, {id: 2, name: 'printer'},{id: 3, name: 'scanner'],
                outofstock: {item_1: false, item_2: true, item_3: false}
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: so do you want `outofstock.item_1` or `outofstock.item_1 bg-green-500` or `bg-green-500`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works without calling a method: [Vue Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

```html
<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in items">
      <div :class="outofstock['item_' + item.id] ? 'bg-green-500' : 'bg-red-500' ">
        {{ item.name }}
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        items: [{ id: 1, name: 'monitor'}, { id: 2, name: 'printer'}, { id: 3, name: 'scanner'}],
        outofstock: {
          item_1: false,
          item_2: true,
          item_3: false
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
<style>
  .bg-green-500 {
    background-color: green;
  }
  .bg-red-500 {
    background-color: red
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answers, and may I ask you to show me what could be solved better?

Comment: I know, I check all solutions and thanks for them. I realy dont know yet how stackowerflow working. I thanking you in coments and at this time I dont see that comment. And I see in all 3 answer, I set a useful a answer. Thank you again for helping me.

Comment: @StEvE, you're welcome, the question in comment above is for tauzN

Answer (score 2):

Define a `computed` property that returns a function which takes the item id as parameter, then use string template `` to render the right class :

```html
<template>
<ul>
    <li v-for="item in items">
        <div :class="`${getItemValue(item.id) ? 'bg-green-500' : 'bg-red-500' }`">
            {{ item.name }}
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</template>

<script>   
    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                items: [{id: 1, name: 'monitor'}, {id: 2, name: 'printer'},{id: 3, name: 'scanner'],
                outofstock: {item_1: false, item_2: true, item_3: false}
            }
        },
   computed:{
       getItemValue(){
         return (id)=>this.outofstock[`item_${id}`];
       }
     }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create method and return right value:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      items: [{id: 1, name: 'monitor'}, {id: 2, name: 'printer'},{id: 3, name: 'scanner'}],
      outofstock: {item_1: false, item_2: true, item_3: false}
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getOutofstock(id) {
      return this.outofstock[id]
    }
  }
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```css
.bg-green-500 {
  color: green;
}
.bg-red-500 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
<ul>
    <li v-for="item in items">
        <div :class="getOutofstock('item_'+item.id) ? 'bg-green-500' : 'bg-red-500' ">
            {{ item.name }}
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```